# Auth Guard not working correctly even when Logged in, redirecting always to login page

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular-router-guards

When I try to access url or redirect the page when **NOT** logged in, it worked fine, then when I **LOGGED IN** I can't still access that page, and redirecting me to the login page. Advice please thank you!

**Auth.service.ts**

```
//Import complete...
...
... 
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  user$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router
  ) {    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState;
  }



  login(email: string, password: string){
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
      value => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("loggedIn", email);
        console.log('Success!', value);
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      }
    ).catch(err=>{
      console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
      this.router.navigate(['sign-up']);
    })
  }
```

**Auth.guard.ts** **(EDITED)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router} from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router)
  {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if(this.authService.isLoggedIn){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return this.router.parseUrl("/sign-in");
    }

  }

}
```

In the App.module.ts - I added the provider

```
  providers: [BookService, AuthService, AuthGuard],
```

Lastly, the **app-routing.module.ts**

```
//Imports 
..
..
..
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/sign-in', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'books', component: BooksComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'add-book', component: AddBookComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent },
  { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic seems to be fine, BUT! You are checking for a value in the localstorage named **'currentUser'**, but you are not setting any value to that key in localstorage in your AuthService's login function. You are just setting a value to **'loggedIn'** in the login function.

Changing this line in AuthGuard

```
if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
```

to

```
if (localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')) {
```

will resolve this error.

Edit :- You are setting the value loggedIn in AuthService to the sessionStorage and in the AuthGuard you are checking the value from localStorage. What's the reason for that?

Comment: still not working :( , but here's the problem sir, when Im **NOT LOGGED IN** then I redirect it to `http://localhost:4200/add-book` then it works fine, it logged me back to log in page, and just what I wanted. **BUT WHEN I LOGGED IN** and go to 
 the link `http://localhost:4200/add-book` it redirect me to logged in page :( how's that ..

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz with your code for we can elaborate? There may be some other cases that will not shown in the above codes

Comment: Hi! , is there other logic of  `canActive()` I'm not quite sure of my logic though.

Comment: what about the **LOGIN** component? should we include it?

Comment: Yeah. Only thing is you are using two kind of storages (sessionStorage in login service and localstorage in AuthGuard). As i said, it will be better if you attach a stackblitz to here.

Comment: sir, I've made changes with my auth guard. ts the problem is the `isLoggedIn` is an error. do you know why? it says `Property 'isLoggedIn' does not exist on type 'AuthService'.`

Comment: Yeah of course. You don't have any function named ***isLoggedIn*** in the Auth.Service.ts file. Add a function to check whether the sessionStorage has the item "loggedIn" like ***if (sessionStorage.getItem("loggedIn")) return true***

Comment: hello sir, I just wanted to ask you if you're aware that I'm using `firebase` as my database?

Comment: Yes. That doesn't have any impact on this issue it seems.